# ¿Como puedo hacer que la función history navegue con un hash en url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero implementar la navegación mediante la función history, pero no me funciona usan un hash(#) en la url.
Estoy usando este plugin ([page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/)) para implementar la navegación mediante la función history.
Pero no me carga nada usando un hash(#) en la url.
¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

```
// Ejemplo simple
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).prop('href');
  page(url);
});


// Ejemplo con ajax
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).prop('href');
  page(url, function(ctx){
    $.ajax({
      url: ctx.path,
      success: function(data){
        $('body').empty().append(data);
      }
    });
  });

  page.redirect(url);
});
```

Comment: Mi ejemplo es el mismo que se da en la pagina oficial del plugin.

Comment: Ya puse el ejemplo.

Comment: Por sierto también hay un detalle, el cual es que cuando lo implemento no cumple su función sino hasta que lo uso mediante la función ajax.

Comment: Ahora pronde el ejemplo con ajax.

Comment: según leo en la documentación, debes definir mediante `page(<url>, <callback>)` que pagina cargar. Tienes definidas estas rutas?

Comment: si, en ejemplo que puse lo hago.

Comment: De echo la versión con ajax me funciona pero se traba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez te falta inicializar la librería. Una vez que haz creado tus rutas, debes ejecutar la función `push();` sin argumentos para que la librería comience a realizar su trabajo.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(function () {
function makePageHandler(page) {
 return function () {
     $('#view').html(page);
    }
}

page('/', makePageHandler('Index'));
page('/about', makePageHandler('About'));
page('/contact', makePageHandler('Contact'));
page('*', makePageHandler('Not found'));
page({ hashbang: true });
page('/');

});
```

```css
#view {
    margin-top: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/page.js/1.7.1/page.min.js"></script>

<a href="/">Index</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>

<div id="view"></div>
```

Suerte y Saludos!

Comment: Si lo se, el problema es que no me funciona de esa manera, tengo que hacer un evento click para que funcione. Así: `$('a').click(function(e){ ... });`

Comment: Por sierto como lo haría con la función push()